# Методы шифровки и дешифровки строки

Tags: python, шифрование

Как сделать метод рабочий метод дешифровки

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import DES

key = b'abcdefgh'
text = 'hdjfhjh'



def encrypt(key, text):
    des = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_ECB)
    l_text = b'{text}'
    while len(l_text) % 8 != 0:
        l_text += b' '
    padded_text = l_text
    encrypted_text = des.encrypt(padded_text)
    return encrypted_text


print(encrypt(key, text))
```

Результат: `b'[d\x81\xe5\xda\xc8\x8c,'`

и можно ли получить чисто строку без " b' ' "

Comment: А с другой стороны чего вы хотели? :) Это же бинарное сообщение, а не текстовое. Для текстового приведите его в hex или base64, например. Для представления байтов в base64 используйте `base64.b64encode`, например: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/99ec5746cc93c8f1c143af0a04a42716d3dc5a16/pycryptodome__examples__AES_DES/info_security.py#L30

Comment: @gil9red т.е hex'{text} ' ?

Comment: Или вызвать у байтов `hex`: `b'\xde\xad\xbe\xef'.hex()` / https://stackoverflow.com/a/36149089/5909792 -> `return encrypted_text.hex()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HEX.**

Переменная `encrypted_text` является байтовым массивом (`bytes`) для читабельного представления байтов можно их показывать в виде HEX строки, используя [bytes.hex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex).

Например, строка в вопросе станет такой:

```
print(b'[d\x81\xe5\xda\xc8\x8c'.hex())  # 5b6481e5dac88c
```

А чтобы это работало в функции `encrypt` из вопроса:

```
return encrypted_text.hex()
```

Для обратного получения байтов из HEX строки используйте метод [bytes.fromhex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex):

```
print(bytes.fromhex('5b6481e5dac88c'))  # b'[d\x81\xe5\xda\xc8\x8c'
```

---

**Base64.**

Еще можно вернуть строку закодированную как [Base64](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Для этого используйте метод [base64.b64encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode):

```
import base64

data = b'[d\x81\xe5\xda\xc8\x8c'

# Результат будет в виде байтов
print(base64.b64encode(data))                  # b'W2SB5drIjA=='

# Результат в виде строки
print(base64.b64encode(data).decode('utf-8'))  # W2SB5drIjA==
```

А чтобы это работало в функции `encrypt` из вопроса (возвращая строку):

```
return base64.b64encode(encrypted_text).decode('utf-8')
```

Для получения байтов из base64 строки используйте метод [base64.b64decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode):

```
# Получение байтов из Base64 строки
print(base64.b64decode(b'W2SB5drIjA=='))       # b'[d\x81\xe5\xda\xc8\x8c'
```

---

**PS.**

Что-то я увлекся темой представления байтов и не заметил вопрос о расшифровки.

Попробуйте:

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import DES

def pad(s: bytes, bs=8) -> bytes:
    pad_size = bs - (len(s) % bs)
    return s + bytes([pad_size] * pad_size)

def unpad(s: bytes) -> bytes:
    pad_size = s[-1]
    return s[:-pad_size]

def encrypt(key: bytes, text: str) -> bytes:
    des = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_ECB)
    l_text = bytes(text, 'utf-8')
    padded_text = pad(l_text)
    encrypted_text = des.encrypt(padded_text)
    return encrypted_text

def decrypt(key: bytes, cipher_text: bytes) -> str:
    des = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_ECB)
    text = des.decrypt(cipher_text)
    return unpad(text).decode('utf-8')

key = b'abcdefgh'
text = 'hdjfhjh'

cipher_text = encrypt(key, text)
print(cipher_text)                # b'\xce{\x17\xdd\xf7\xe3\xef\xe1'
print(decrypt(key, cipher_text))  # hdjfhjh
```

Код для `pad` и `unpad` взял [отсюда](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/82810f8397907679316107f135a5b1dd1fcca516/pad__unpad__example.py#L7).